# I have XBOX Live but on MW3 my guest can't play?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, xbox-network

I've played Modern Warfare 3 before with a guest and I redeemed my code just an hour before. It just keeps on saying "Can't sign in" and it's really annoying - can anyone help?

Comment: Can you sign on without a guest?

Comment: Yes that's the weird thing

Answer (score 5):

You can't sign in while a guest is also logged in. To get this to work you need to

1. Make sure **every profile** except for your Xbox Live Gold account is logged out
2. Go to Multiplayer >> Xbox Live and get signed in
3. Hit the A button on another controller

Xbox Live won't let you sign in to Call of Duty Multiplayer with any profiles that aren't gold logged in. The "Guest" account technically isn't gold, so you're getting rejected for that. Adding a guest player is done on the Call of Duty server, not your Xbox.

Comment: Should note that in MW2, you couldn't do 2 player on the same console on XBox live at the same time. Every player had to be on his own game and console.